# Create jQuery infinite loop

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make an infinite loop in jQuery. I understood the basic syntax was

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function helloworld() {
    alert("hello, world!");
helloworld();
}
});
```

... but this does nothing. How would I do this? Thanks!

Comment: just call function with helloworld(); then it's starting with infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function helloworld() {
    alert("hello, world!");
    helloworld();
}
helloworld();
});
```

Comment: Thanks - this is what I'd been trying actually - forgot to type it in properly. So the problem must be with my internal function - I shall create a new question...

Answer (score 0):

```
while (1) {
    alert("hello, world!");
}
```

use this this will alert infinite time

Answer (score 0):

This is also infinite function :D

```
function myfn() {
    console.log("hello, there!");
    myfn();
}
myfn();
```